# Avoid word breaking on first line with CSS

Tags: css, text, line, word-wrap

I have some trouble with a container that has comments of users.

What it looks like:

```
Firstname Lastname -
Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur.
Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commod risus.
```

What I want to change it to:

```
Firstname Lastname - Aenean lacinia bibendum
nulla sed consectetur. Fusce dapibus,
tellus ac cursus commod risus.
```

So the text will continue on the first line until its out of space and then it will go on new line to continue.

jsFiddle: [jsfiddle.net/qhY34/7](http://jsfiddle.net/qhY34/7)

Comment: Can you give more information?  How is the comment generated?  What does the html look like?

Comment: Is there a newline character in the user's comment? You may have to filter those out and replace them with spaces.

Comment: It shouldn't be doing that. If a word can fit in the space, it will be put there. If it can't, it'll wrap to the second line. The width of the container looks like it should be enough. Provide us with your HTML/CSS please. My guess is that there is a newline after the name.

Comment: Create a jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/.

Comment: provide some html markup please.

Comment: without code we can't possibly help figure out why the code isn't working

Comment: here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qhY34/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `word-break: break-all;`

instead of 
`word-wrap: break-word;`

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qhY34/8/